# C# Regex Replace Question

Tags: .net, regex, replace

if i have a string like this "Hello - World - Hello World"

I want to replace the characters PRECEDING the FIRST instance of the substring " - "

e.g. so replacing the above with "SUPERDOOPER" would leave: "SUPERDOOPER - World - Hello World"

So far I got this: "^[^-]* - "

But this INCLUDES the " - " which is wrong.

how to do this with regex please?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [non-capturing group](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/NoGroup.html), which looks ahead of the pattern to verify the match, but does not include those characters in the match itself.

```
(^[^-]*)(?: -)
```

Edit: after thinking about it again, that seems a little redundant. Wouldn't this work?:

```
^[^-]*
```

Gets all non-dash characters between the beginning of the string and continues until it hits a dash? Or do you need to exclude the space as well? If so, go with the first one.

Comment: Non-capturing group will not create group, but will include that its part into the whole match (group #0). So, your first example won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that you need to use a regular expression for a string operation like this?

This is simpler and more efficent:

```
str = "SUPERDOOPER" + str.Substring(str.IndexOf(" -"));
```

Comment: thanks Guffa, this is the solution i went with. Thanks to everybody else for their replies too. I learned a lot from this post. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do this?

Regex.Replace("World - Hello World", "^[^-]* -", "SUPERDOOPER -");

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(Hello)( -.*\1)", @"SUPERDOOPER$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern: 
    ([^-]+) (- .+)

First expression matches any series of chars not including a dash.
Then there's a space.
Second expression starts with a dash and a space, followed by a series of one or more "any" chars.

The replacement:  "Superdooper $2"

delivers
  Superdooper - World - Hello World

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex with positive lookahead: `"^[^-]*(?= - )"`. As far as I know C# supports it. This regex will match *exactly* what you want. You can find out more about lookahead, look-behind and other advanced regex techniques in famous book ["Mastering Regular Expressions"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124).